# How to test [routerLink] values rendered from Angular component string array?

Tags: javascript, angular, testing, karma-jasmine

I need test `[routerLink]` values rendered from string array of my Angular component.

This is TypeScript file:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.css']
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

  title: string = 'Blog App';
  links = [
    { name: 'Home', route: '/home' },
    { name: 'Blog', route: '/blog' },
    { name: 'Create article', route: '/create' }
  ];

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

This is HTML file:

```html
<header id="header">
    <div class="center">
      <div id="logo">
        <img src="assets/images/angular.svg" class="app-logo" alt="angular-logo" />
        <span id="brand">
          <strong>{{title}}</strong>
        </span>
      </div>
        <nav id="menu">
            <ul>
                <li *ngFor="let link of links">
                    <a [routerLink]="[ link.route ]" [routerLinkActive]="['active']">{{ link.name }}</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
</header>
```

And this is the test:

```js
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { HeaderComponent } from './header.component';

describe('HeaderComponent', () => {
  let component: HeaderComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<HeaderComponent>;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ HeaderComponent ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(HeaderComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });
  
  it('should have nav links href equal to /home, /blog and /create', () => {
    const linksRoute = ['/home', '/blog', '/create'];
    document.querySelectorAll("nav#menu ul > li > a").forEach((el, i) => {
      expect(el.getAttribute('href')).toEqual(linksRoute[i]);
    });
  });
});
```

And the result I get:

[Expected result of test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hbox1.png)

Answer (score 0):

You don't receive an error for this? I would imagine you to receive an error for this because the TestBed module would not know what `routerLink` is.

I would do this:

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';
....

describe('HeaderComponent', () => {
  let component: HeaderComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<HeaderComponent>;
  // declare router
  let router: Router;
  // we will make sure navigateSpy is called
  let navigateSpy: jasmine.Spy;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      // import RouterTestingModule so routerLinks means something 
      // and do not error out
      imports: [RouterTestingModule],
      declarations: [ HeaderComponent ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    // get a handle on the router
    router = TestBed.inject(Router);
    // assign navigateSpy to router.navigate
    navigateSpy = spyOn(router, 'navigate');
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(HeaderComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });
  
  it('should navigate to accurate links', () => {
    const linksRoute = ['/home', '/blog', '/create'];
    // I like using debugElement to query the DOM/HTML
    const links = fixture.debugElement.queryAll(By.css('nav#menu ul > li > a'));
    // check after clicking the link that router.navigate was called accurately
    links.forEach((link, i) => {
       const element = link.nativeElement;
       element.click();
       expect(navigateSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith([linksRoute[i]]);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response @AliF50, but when I run your test, Jasmine gives me an errors.
```
Expected spy navigate to have been called with:
  [ [ 'home' ] ]
but it was never called.
```

Comment: Ok sorry about that. I am thinking that the `routerLink` is not bound to `router.navigate` then so it does not get called. Try running your test (the one that you have) and see if it passes.